# Using JSON in Android Studio in php style

Tags: json, android-studio

I read JSON from [webpage](http://quiz.xnicram.pl/getTest.php) and now I want convert it to array and use like in php. In php I do it like that:

```
//$json - this is my json STRING readed from webpage
$trueJSON = json_decode($json,true);
$q = $trueJSON['test']['questions'][1]['question'];
$a1 = $trueJSON['test']['questions'][1]['answers']['a1'];
$a2 = $trueJSON['test']['questions'][1]['answers']['a2'];
$a3 = $trueJSON['test']['questions'][1]['answers']['a3'];
$a4 = $trueJSON['test']['questions'][1]['answers']['a4'];
$a5 = $trueJSON['test']['questions'][1]['answers']['a5'];
$a = $trueJSON['test']['questions'][1]['correctAnswer'];
```

In Android Studio to get json string from web I use this class:

```
public class TalkToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String response = HttpRequest.get(params[0]).body();
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // and here I want to decode JSON string result to Array
        // and next use this array on whole Activity
    }
}
public void click(View view) {
    TalkToServer task = new TalkToServer();
    task.execute("http://quiz.xnicram.pl/getTest.php");
}
```

**If possible then how to create in `onPostExecute` array which i can use in similar way to my php example?**

PS. Sorry for my English :/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code

```
JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray(/*Array Name */ );
```

Comment: I try instead `/*Array Name */` type "test", "name", "questions" and every time I got error message "... cannot be converted to JSONArray", here is my json string http://quiz.xnicram.pl/getTest.php and it's vaild JSON

Comment: this because you may write invalid format for JSON data

Comment: my json string is VALID JSON i will check it with few tools

Comment: if it VALID as you say you should write `test` ... may you give me screenshot from error please ?